# How to perform mean subtraction, normalization AND PCA and Whitening with KERAS on the CIFAR10 data set

Tags: python, keras, theano

On http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/ it is mentioned that for convolutional neural networks it is preferred to preprocess data using mean subtraction, PCA and Whitening and normalization techniques.

I was just wondering how to implement the following with keras using theano backend.

1. center the data to have mean of zero, and normalize its scale to [-1, 1] along each feature
2. Initialize the weights by drawing them from a gaussian distribution with standard deviation of 2/n−−−√2/n, where n is the number of inputs to the neuron. E.g. in numpy: w = np.random.randn(n) * sqrt(2.0/n).
3. Use L2 regularization and dropout (the inverted version)
4. Use batch normalization

Comment: 2: use keras.initializers.VarianceScaling